# Is there reasoning behind choosing a specific object?

Tags: java, multithreading, object, synchronization

Is the locking object used for synchronization arbitrary or is there reasoning behind choosing a specific object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why would you lock an object? Because it is shared among various threads. That's all there is. How you implement locking and threading is probably the difficult part, as opposed to choosing which object to lock on.

Comment: I now see what you're saying. Thanks.

Comment: Well, Nate asked for the reasoning behind deciding on which object to lock on. I think you mentioned some of the locking techniques, and I agree with you. But that wasn't the question. Interesting username btw, very apt :)

Answer (score 2):

You'd be better off using one of the more modern locking techniques where much of the complexity and pitfalls have been removed/smoothed over. [Package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/package-summary.html) `java.util.concurrent.locks` would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather unclear.

You may be referring to a Semaphore object as a lock. You may also be referring to synchronized objects.

1) A semaphore may as well arbitrary object. It's intended purpose is that it can be used to hold threads at the semaphore until other threads release it.

2) Synchronized objects make all of their functions atomic: If a thread is operating on the object, the other object waits to complete its own function. This is usually implemented using a semaphore internally.

Semaphores are the objects used to solve synchronization problems.

Answer (score 1):

The locking object needs to represent the exclusive part.

if you lock the whole object meaning using it exclusively by an thread, you may use the object "this" to lock. This is the way "synchronize" work on methods work.

```
 public class A
 {
    public synchronized void do1 ()
    {
    ...
    }
    public synchronized void do2 ()
    {
    ...
    }
 }
```

if your object just has some set of members which should be used exclusively, you need separate (explicit) locking objects

```
 public class B
 {
    private X x;
    private Y y;
    private Object lockXY = new Object ();

    private R r;
    private S s;
    private Object lockRS = new Object ();

    public void do1 ()
    {
       synchronize (lockXY) {
       }
    ...
    }
    public void do2 ()
    {
       synchronize (lockRS) {
       }
    }
 }
```

Beware to make locking to complex, you may run into dead locks

Answer (score 1):

As in the accepted answer, the object you choose is arbitrary, just make sure you use it correctly. However, some objects are better than others. It's best practice not to use some object that may be accessible outside the context of the locking - if it is some other piece of code may also decide to synchronize on it, or call notify on it or whatever. So preferably use java.util.concurrent instead, or use private objects.